# Check if trunk commit was merged from branch

Tags: svn

I've done a svn merge using the following command from the working directory of trunk:

```
svn merge -rXXXX:YYYY branch_directory_path
```

and then committed my changes. Usually I know if the commit was a result of a merge by adding that to the commit message, such as "Merged from branch ....".

Is there a way to know that this commit happened after a merge from branch without explicitly adding that to the commit message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Subversion 1.5 or above (and you should), you can always look at the value of *svn:mergeinfo*:

```
$ svn propget -R svn:mergeinfo $branch_directory_path
```

This will print out the branch and the range of revisions merged into that particular branch.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `--use-merge-history` option of `svn log`.

See SVN's [Merge Tracking Functional Specification](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/merge-tracking/func-spec.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just look at a branch graph - SmartSVN has a pretty good one.